# EntityFramework Rollback All Transactions if One Object Fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this scenario that I'm about to add records to 5 or more tables consecutively. The saving mechanism should be strict that any object fails all database changes will not be committed or be rolled back. If all objects were inserted without issue that's the time that all records should be saved to database. Bellow is my sample code. Please help.

```
_dbContext.Table1.AddObject(object1);//if insert fails rollback
_dbContext.SaveChanges();


_dbContext.Table2.AddObject(object2);//if insert fails rollback this and object1 transactions
_dbContext.SaveChanges();


_dbContext.Table3.AddObject(object3);//if insert fails rollback this and previous other transactions
_dbContext.SaveChanges();


_dbContext.Table4.AddObject(object4);//if insert fails rollback this and previous other transactions
_dbContext.SaveChanges();

_dbContext.Table5.AddObject(object5);//if insert fails rollback this and previous other transactions
_dbContext.SaveChanges();

//if all objects were inserted without exceptions then commit all changes
```

Comment: Call `SaveChanges()` one time at the end, EF wrap all inside a transaction scope, except operations not related directly to EF like I/O operations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you could just do this:

```
_dbContext.Table1.AddObject(object1);
_dbContext.Table2.AddObject(object2);
_dbContext.Table3.AddObject(object3);
_dbContext.Table4.AddObject(object4);
_dbContext.Table5.AddObject(object5);
_dbContext.SaveChanges(); // if fails will roll back all objects
```

Comment: Amazing! I thought the implementation is complicated. Thanks